# cant resolve TabLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In xml_file line number 18 and in java_file line number 24 is showing in red colour, can't understand why ?
And for these two lines cant use TabLayout.

### build.gradle

```
dependencies 
{

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
    //for authentication purpose
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
    //for database purpose
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.3'
    //for maintenance purpose
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.3'
    //for storing data purpose like images
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    //for general designing
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
    //for parsing data purpose(we are adding few libraries in advance to avoid wasting time)
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.1'
}
```

### XML file

```xml
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">    
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout">
    
            <include
                layout = '@layout/app_bar_layout'
                android:id="@+id/main_page_toolbar"
                >
            </include>
    
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
       
        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/main_tabs_pager"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout">
       </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

### java file

```java
    package com.example.myapplication;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
    import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
    
    import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
    
    import java.util.Objects;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        private Toolbar mToolbar;
        private ViewPager myViewPager;
        private TabLayout myTabLayout;
        private TabsAccessorAdapter myTabsAccessorAdapter;
    
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("ChatApp");
    
            myViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_tabs_pager);
            myTabsAccessorAdapter = new TabsAccessorAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            myViewPager.setAdapter(myTabsAccessorAdapter);
    
            myTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_tabs);
            myTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(myViewPager);
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have edited this to remove line numbers from the code. There's no need to have them, people would paste this lot into an IDE if they wanted to reproduce it.

Comment: You are mixing support libraries and androidx based libraries. Use com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing support libraries and androidx libraries and you can't do it.

Remove:

```
//implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
//implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
//implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
```

Use:

```
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
  implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:x.x.x'
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

And in your layout/code use **`com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout`**

Comment: Still its not working, when im running the app its opening for once and then the whole app crashes.

Comment: @ArijitRoy It is another issue, completely unrelated with the question.

Comment: Yes but what is its solution ?

Comment: How can someone provide a solution if you don't post the issue? Post another question with all details.